# Difference between valgrind and system("leaks a.out")

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, system, valgrind

In the C language, memory management and memory leaks are among the most confusing topics in my opinion. The most commonly used method to control this is valgrind. However, Mac computers are used in my course, and instead of valgrind, the function system("leaks a.out") is used on these computers. I tried both methods on my own computer at home, which has Windows and Ubuntu operating systems, and compared the results. I obtained different results, as valgrind showed even the smallest leaks, while with the system("leaks a.out") function, I only obtained leaks in specific codes.

I also searched many sources and could not find any source on how to use the system("leaks a.out") function. Can someone who is familiar with the use of this function explain why I obtained different results? I thought I knew about memory leaks, but after discovering the system("leaks a.out") function, everything I knew got mixed up.

As a result, this is the summary: I tried both of this function (system("leaks a.out")) and program (valgrind). I expected same result but got different. Because leaks are leaks, it must not be changed, right?

Comment: `system("leaks a.out");` is just a `system()` function to actually invoke a shell command `> leaks a.out`, while `leaks` is just a command line utility like `valgrind`, and you can find how to use it buy invoking `man leaks`.

Comment: "memory management and memory leaks are among the most confusing topics" -- citation needed.

Comment: Not all memory error detection methods are created equal?

Comment: I wanted to make an effective introduction, but I used a wrong sentence and spoke on behalf of everyone by using a general expression while expressing my own opinion, so I edited that part. Now, if everything is okay, can you give me suggestion? @Blindy

Comment: Thank you for your comment, i tried it but my terminal says "command not found" when i wrote "leaks" or "man leaks". Now i am researching it, to how i install it. @EugeneSh.

Comment: It seems so, you are right. But still, it does not make sense to me. If system("leaks a.out") doesn't show leaks even in places where there are leaks, wouldn't that indicate that it's not a very reliable function? @Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Not all equal? Kind of.

If the tool can see all calls to allocation and deallocation then leak detection is fairly straightforward.

There are a couple of cases where tools don't get all the info they need.

1. If the tool does not start recording from the very beginning. For instance `leaks` can attach to a PID. Memory that is allocated before the attach won't be tracked.
2. User-defined allocation functions. Generally these require annotation to be recognized by tools, otherwise leaks don't get detected.

Of course, there is also always the possibility of tools having bugs.

Most tools also have some sort of suppression mechanism (with a set of default suppressions). It's probably this that causes differences in what you are seeing.

Run Valgrind with -s to see which suppressions it is using.